# 'GinjectorGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding '...ClientGinjector'

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, guice, gwt-gin, gwtp

I'm getting this error when running my web application that use GWT, GWT-Platform and App engine:

> Generator 'com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator' threw an
>   exception while rebinding 'com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjector'

My application have these jars in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder:

```
guice-3.0.jar  
gin-1.5-post-gwt-2.2.jar
guice-servlet-3.0.jar
gwtp-all-0.7.jar
```

Here's the detailed error log of `Development Mode`:

> [DEBUG] [app] - Validating newly compiled units [DEBUG]  [app] -
>   Rebinding com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjector     [DEBUG] [app] -
>   Invoking generator com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator
>   [ERROR] [app] - Generator
>   'com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator' threw an exception
>   while rebinding 'com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjector'
>
> [ERROR] [app] - Deferred binding failed for
>   'com.myapp.client.gin.ClientGinjector'; expect subsequent failures
>   [ERROR]  [app] - Failed to create an instance of
>   'com.myapp.client.MainAppEntryPoint' via deferred binding
>
> [ERROR] [app] - Unable to load module entry point class
>   com.myapp.client.MainAppEntryPoint (see associated exception for
>   details)
>
> [ERROR] [app] - Failed to load module 'app' from user agent
>   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11' at 127.0.0.1:53782

I've been trying to figure out what could have been missing in my application but I still can't find the fix? What is causing this kind of error?

Comment: Try doing a GWT compile -- that sometimes yields better error messages.

Comment: additionally you can change the logLevel of the compile to debug so you get even more detailed descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times this is due to adding non gwt supported types  or imports such as java.net.* etc in your client folders of a gwt project.  Only java types that are supported in the gwt white list are supported and can be searialized.  the rebinding errors mask those errors.  So comb through your project and see if you have those types and imports included in either client or shared folders

Comment: Beware when Eclipse generates import statements for ambiguous objects: it asks you which one to use, but if you choose too fast, you find yourself with something like `jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Objects` instead of `com.google.common.base.Objects`. The latter is GWTCompatible while the latter isn't!
Go to Preferences, search `type filters`, add `jersey.repackaged.*` to the list. I also have `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.*` and `com.google.gwt.dev.*` there, among others.